# Граф связей людей на Python

Tags: python, графы, связи

Есть набор данных в табличном виде с информацией о людях. С помощью каких библиотек Python можно построить граф или дерево связей по ним? Например выбираем человека через фильтр или с помощью ввода textbox и тд, получаем граф связей, где главной вершиной является выбранный человек, далее второй вершиной параметр по которому есть связь, третий уровень вершин - это человек с которым есть связь.
Кода пока нет, подскажите с чего начать, может есть какие-то шаблоны на python?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, наверное NetworkX https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/tutorial.html